# How to fill WinRT/XAML paragraph with variable height element?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, inlineuicontainer

Suppose I have a RichTextBlock with 2 paragraphs. The second paragraph is just some text. The first paragraph is a FlipView with images like a slideshow. What properties on the `<Paragraph>` or the `<InlineUIContainer>` or the `<FlipView>` should I set so that if the FlipView's images have different heights, the second paragraph text would move to stack just underneath the image in the FlipView?

Comment: Do you mean WPF or WinRT/XAML? It sounds like you are talking about WinRT/XAML, but you say WPF?

Comment: Could you bind the Width/Height properties of the FlipView to the Width/Height of its SelectedItem? Wouldn't it work better though if the images were scaled to fit the FlipView instead? I feel like text reflowing when you change a selected item would not work too well for the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can with a FlipView.

The FlipView will have a rectangular clipping to make sure none of the other items appear in the view box. The dimensions (width/height) of this view box are based on the values you explicitly set, or chosen by the parent container. They do not change based on the images *inside* the FlipView.